# Radio buttons checked however passing NULL to database

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, radio-button

I have 4 groups of radio buttons that are presented unchecked to the user. The user then needs to check one radio button for each group. When I submit this form, the error I get is that, for example, for `picture_6.tif` the value being passed is `NULL`.

I am using CodeIgniter and the form is being submitted via POST.
I wonder if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```html
<form action="/log" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <table class="static">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_6.tif" value="0" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_7.tif" value="0" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_8.tif" value="0" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_9.tif" value="0" class=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_6.tif" value="1" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_7.tif" value="1" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_8.tif" value="1" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_9.tif" value="1" class=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_6.tif" value="2" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_7.tif" value="2" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_8.tif" value="2" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_9.tif" value="2" class=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_6.tif" value="3" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_7.tif" value="3" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_8.tif" value="3" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_9.tif" value="3" class=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_6.tif" value="9" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_7.tif" value="9" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_8.tif" value="9" class=""></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="picture_9.tif" value="9" class=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit Post!">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

EDIT: Just adding this to make it easier for searching. The error arises from using  periods in a `name` attribute.

Comment: If the user has to check one button for each group then you need to change the naming of the each group. you are using the same for all

Comment: but then how would I provide the options I need? for example, for the `picture_6.tif` group, the user would need to choose from one of the radio buttons (each has a different value). Same for the other groups. Changing the names will not give that functionality, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: there's a problem interpreting `value="0"` as `null` so we need to see the PHP to find the exact cause

Comment: value `0` is hardcoded in the HTML view page; changing for another value results in the same error

Comment: Wait, now let me ask you a question, if picture_6.tif is selected in the first group can it be selected in the second

Comment: if you select the radio button with name `picture_6.tif` in the first stack of radio buttons, then decide to select the `picture_6.tif` radio button in the second stack, the first one is unchecked -- you can sse this behavior in the neat new feature **run code snippet** below my code

Comment: Oh then why do you need different values

Comment: All you need is to check with their names and leave the values for HTML to provide

Comment: So you just leave the value attribute, and in php you check if the checkbox is empty or not, if empty it means it was unchecked, else it was checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your `radio` `name="picture_6.tif"` and in php your parameters available as `$_POST["picture_6_tif"]`. Note: **not** `$_POST["picture_6.tif"]`. The latter is null as undefined.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
//array(5) { ["picture_7_tif"]=> string(1) "1" ["picture_6_tif"]=> string(1) "2" ["picture_8_tif"]=> string(1) "3" ["picture_9_tif"]=> string(1) "9" ["mysubmit"]=> string(12) "Submit Post!" }
```

Comment: wow, what a great catch! I was completely unaware that POST can't handle the  `.` and converts it to `_`.

Comment: Dot `.` is string concatenation operator in PHP so PHP converts dot to underscore in received form parameters `$_POST`, `$_GET`, and so on.